# What is Process Heap?

Tags: .net, memory-management, compilation

Recently I was reading a book "Under the hood of .NET memory management" the author mentioned process heap few times and written that he will talk about it in the last chapters. Unfortunately there was nothing about Process Heap there )

Can anybody advice some books or materials to read on it ?

Thanks.

Comment: A program on Windows can create any number of heaps, underlying winapi call is HeapCreate().  But two of them are special and always available.  The default process heap (GetProcessHeap()) is one of them, it is the heap that Windows itself uses.  Also available in .NET through Marshal.AllocHGlobal().  Mark Russinovich's Windows Internals is never a bad selection.

Comment: Thanks, now I know where to start. )

Comment: #davit can you Please explain what is it

Answer (score 1):

a heap is an area of pre-reserved computer main storage ( memory ) that a program process can use to store data in some variable amount that won't be known until the program is running. For example, a program may accept different amounts of input from one or more users for processing and then do the processing on all the input data at once.